# Is it bad to have many global functions?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I'm relatively new to software development, and I'm on my way to completing my first app for the iPhone.

While learning Swift, I learned that I could add functions outside the class definition, and have it accessible across all views. After a while, I found myself making many global functions for setting app preferences (registering defaults, UIAppearance, etc).

Is this bad practice? The only alternate way I could think of was creating a custom class to encapsulate them, but then the class itself wouldn't serve any purpose and I'd have to think of ways to passing it around views.

Comment: Thank you guys for the insightful discussion. I knew that global things in programming aren't good in general (which is why I asked the question in the first place), but I didn't know global functions can serve good purpose if it's general enough and will be used often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global functions: good (IMHO anyway, though some disagree)

Global state: bad (fairly universally agreed upon)

By which I mean, it’s probably a good practice to break up your code to create lots of small utility functions, to make them general, and to re-use them.  So long as they are “[pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)”

For example, suppose you find yourself checking if all the entries in an array have a certain property.  You might write a for loop over the array checking them.  You might even re-use the standard `reduce` to do it.  Or you could write a re-useable function, `all`, that takes a closure that checks an element, and runs it against every element in the array.  It’s nice and clear when you’re reading code that goes `let allAboveGround = all(sprites) { $0.position.y > 0 }` rather than a `for…in` loop that does the same thing.  You can also write a separate unit test specifically for your `all` function, and be confident it works correctly, rather than a much more involved test for a function that includes embedded in it a version of `all` amongst other business logic.

Breaking up your code into smaller functions can also help avoid needing to use `var` so much.  For example, in the above example you would probably need a `var` to track the result of your looping but the result of the `all` function can be assigned using `let`.  Favoring immutable variables declared with `let` can help make your program easier to reason about and debug.

What you shouldn’t do, as @drewag points out in his answer, is write functions that change global variables (or access singletons which amount to the same thing).  Any global function you write should operate only on their inputs and produce the exact same results every time regardless of when they are called.  Global functions that mutate global state (i.e. make changes to global variables (or change values of variables passed to them as arguments by reference) can be incredibly confusing to debug due to unexpected side-effects they might cause.

There is one downside to writing pure global functions,* which is that you end up “polluting the namespace” – that is, you have all these functions lying around that might have specific relevance to a particular part of your program, but accessible everywhere.  To be honest, for a medium-sized application, with well-written generic functions named sensibly, this is probably not an issue.  If a function is purely of use to a specific struct or class, maybe make it a static method.  If your project really is getting too big, you could perhaps factor out your most general functions into a separate framework, though this is quite a big overhead/learning exercise (and Swift frameworks aren’t entirely fully-baked yet), so if you are just starting out so I’d suggest leaving this for now until you get more confident.

* edit: ok two downsides – member functions are more discoverable (via autocomplete when you hit .)

Comment: I like this explanation. I think my only disagreement would be that I would mark Global functions as "neutral" instead of good. You can break up code into small units within either functions or types. I don't think either is inherently better except potentially types are better because of the polluted namespace issue you mentioned.

Comment: When there is a suitable solution that involves creating a type, sure. The trouble is, where else to put truly generic functions?  Suppose you wrote my hypothetical `all` function, that worked on any sequence.  Unless they add something like the ability to extend protocols, there’s nowhere for that function to belong.  Should it go inside a struct as a static method?  That’s the Java way and personally I don’t like living in the [kingdom of nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: Another way of looking at it: look at the Swift standard library.  What’s the proportion of free functions to member functions, about 50/50?  (again possibly because we don’t have something like traits yet – wouldn’t be surprised to see this in 2.0).  OK so this is a highly generic library not an app, but I still think it can act as a style guide.

Comment: Ya agreed. Your all example is a great example of a function that should be global. I also dislike creating a custom type just for a collection of static method, unless discoverability is going to be an issue. An encapsulating type can be nice for autocomplete.

Comment: Also OP mentioned specifically global functions that are affecting state: most importantly, setting app preferences.

Comment: Yeah, Lattner recently posted on the forum about how member functions help discoverability through autocomplete and that might sway them in their direction in future - that’s why I have a feeling this will end up with generic functions being extensions to protocols.  Or they could go the route C++ is probably going and make f(x,y) callable as x.f(y).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67390/discussion-between-airspeed-velocity-and-drewag).

Answer (score 3):

**Updated after discussion with @AirspeedVelocity**

Global functions can be ok and they really aren't much different than having type methods or even instance methods on a custom type that is not actually intended to contain state.

The entire thing comes down mostly to personal preference. Here are some pros and cons.

**Cons:**

- They sometimes can cause unintended side effects. That is they can change some global state that you or the caller forgets about causing hard to track down bugs. As long as you are careful about not using global variables and ensure that your function always returns the same result with the same input regardless of the state of the rest of the system, you can mostly ignore this con.
- They make code that uses them difficult to test which is important once you start [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) (which is a definite good policy in most circumstances). It is hard to test because you can't mock out the implementation of a global function easily. For example, to change the value of a global setting. Instead your test will start to depend on your other class that sets this global setting. Being able to inject a setting into your class instead of having to fake out a global function is generally preferable.
- They sometimes hint at poor code organization. All of your code should be [separable into small, single purpose, logical units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). This ensures your code will remain understandable as your code base grows in size and age. The exception to this is truly universal functions that have very high level and reusable concepts. For example, a function that lets you test all of the elements in a sequence. You can also still separate global functions into logical units by separating them into well named files.

**Pros:**

- High level global functions can be very easy to test. However, you cannot ignore the need to still test their logic where they are used because your unit test should not be written with knowledge of how your code is actually implemented.
- Easily accessible. It can often be a pain to inject many types into another class (pass objects into an initializer and probably store it as a property). Global functions can often remove this boiler plate code (even if it has the trade off of being less flexible and less testable).

In the end, every code architecture decision is a balance of trade offs each time you go to use it.

Comment: You’re conflating global state with global functions.  The former is bad, the latter is debatable and arguably more suitable in Swift.  Breaking your code into multiple functions should them more unit-testable not less, so long as they are pure functions.  Separate namespaces might be necessary for truly large projects but for a modest iOS project it’s not a big issue.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Global functions often leads to global state. I feel discussing pure functions with someone just getting started with programming is a bad idea. I think the "no global functions" rule is one of those examples of a rule that can be broken once you really understand why it is there in the first place. Too often beginning programmers use them as a crutch (including the overuse of the singleton pattern). Also, global functions cannot be swizzled in Swift making them very hard / impossible to mock.

Comment: "Global functions often leads to global state” I strongly disagree with this statement.  I also think shying away from telling beginner programmers about pure functions and encouraging them to stick to “classic” OOP is doing them a major disservice, especially when the language they are starting with is Swift.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity, you may be right. I do not have too strong of an opinion either way. I just have seen a lot of code from beginners that use both global functions and global state as a crutch rather than the best solution. I am not sure what the best way is to advise against that, but perhaps it is just something everyone learns through experience.

Comment: Totally agree with you that there’s something instinctive about reaching immediately for global state when you’re new to programming, but I feel like that makes taking about immutable state and pure functions _even more_ important (while trying to use accessible language wherever possible, <insert joke about monads just being monoids in the category of endofunctors here>)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity, I updated my answer to be more nuanced but to still reflect my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Framework.swift that contains a set of common global functions like `local(str:String)` to get rid of the 2nd parameter from `NSLocalize`. Also there are a number of `alert` functions internally using `local` and with varying number of parameters which makes use of `NSAlert` as modal dialogs more easy.

So for that purpose global functions are good. They are bad habit when it comes to information hiding where you would expose internal class knowledge to some global functionality.